# Why is the $m/x$ a good approximation of count distinct num in a set when m is max possible value and x is smallest value in the set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am looking at cardinality estimator explanation and intuition in this [blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2012/09/Dam-Cool-Algorithms-Cardinality-Estimation) and I am confused in the following claim.

If a set of numbers was random and evenly distributed.

If the maximum possible value is $m$, and the smallest value we find is $x$, why can we then estimate there to be about $m/x$ unique values in the set?

Answer (score 0):

If you draw $n$ values out of $[1,m]$ and sort them, the expected value of the smallest is $\frac m{n+1}$.  They are inverting this by assuming the smallest is $\frac mn$ (I think ignoring the $+1$) and using it to compute $n$.  The dispersion is quite high.  If you draw just one number, on average the value is $\frac m2$ and if you draw that you would get $2$ as the number of samples taken, but you are just as likely to get $1$ and esimate $m$ or $m$ and estimate $1$.  With larger $n$ you have a higher chance of getting $1$ and estimating $m$ distinct samples.  On the other hand, I don't see a way to do better.

Comment: can you derive the $m/(n+1)$ result? How do I apply $min$ operator in the expectation equation?

Comment: No, I can't derive it.  Thinking again, because the lowest value is $1$ I think it should really be $1+\frac {m-1}{n+1}$ because the expected gaps from the ends to the end points and between the points are the same.

Comment: yeah, I still don't understand why is that intuitively correct, I was hoping a derivation can help me understand a bit better.